# How to show bookmark icon on view in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am creating a bookmark system where users can bookmark a particular product. When I attempt to load the icon for a bookmarked item, it shows both the icon, i.e., before the bookmark icon and the bookmarked icon.

Here's a simple explanation.

```
[{"id":2,"bookmark_id":"HRTKB1607974280","user_id":"HCTK001606935187","document_id":"HRTKD1607941923","created_at":"2020-12-14T19:31:20.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-14T19:31:20.000000Z"},
{"id":3,"bookmark_id":"HRTKB1607974280","user_id":"HCTK001606935187","document_id":"HRTKD1607941923","created_at":"2020-12-14T19:31:20.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-14T19:31:20.000000Z"}]
```

Now in the Blade file, I am using the following code.

```php
@foreach($documents as $data)
    @foreach($bookmarks as $bookmark)
        @if($data->document_id === $bookmark->document_id)
            <li class="active-bookmark">
                <a href="/add_bookmark/{{$data->document_id}}" 
                   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
                   title="Bookmark">
                    <i class="lar la-bookmark"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            @break
        @else
            <li>
                <a href="/add_bookmark/{{$data->document_id}}" 
                   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
                   title="Bookmark">
                    <i class="lar la-bookmark"></i>
                </a></li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endofforeach
```

But for some reason, this is happening.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Remove the `@break`

Comment: I did but still getting the same result

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear` and check again

Comment: Still the same @Donkarnash

Comment: Ahh yes. It will be because you are using another foreach within the foreach for $documents. What happens is that when you loop over $bookmarks in the inner foreach for a $bookmark which matches the if condition you get the active-bookmark class on the li while for the rest you simply output the li without the active class

Comment: Can I solve this issue using leftjoin or something but with pagination? @Donkarnash

Comment: What the bookmark_id in documents records signify - is it that only the documents which are bookmarked have bookmark_id? In that case you can check for notNull bookmark_id to add the active class. Or you can define a relation on document model for bookmark & the check if $data->bookmark->document_id === $data->document_id to apply the active class

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through that loop and will always output a icon until the true condition is met. What happens when the first iteration it isn't met, it has to iterate again and output another icon.

Assuming these are all Collections you can do this without looping the bookmarks:

```
@foreach ($documents as $document)
    ...
    @if ($bookmarks->contains('document_id', $document->id))
        // have the bookmark
    @else
        // add bookmark
    @endif
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Both looks same using this either bookmarked or not bookmarked

Comment: sounds like a css problem

Comment: CSS is fine @lagbox

Comment: pretty hard to actually know what you are doing with this small snippet and a picture that only shows 1 iteration of the loop, this would only let 1 of those logical paths resolve per document, so ...

Comment: Basically I want a bookmark system in product search, User search the product and bookmark the product, then If user return to search after doing order or add to card then it will show bookmarked item in red color in search page